# Why does this series of git-svn commands result in a detached HEAD?

Tags: git, git-svn

I do this:

```
$ git svn clone http://monsterdebugger.googlecode.com/svn/ -s --prefix=svn/ monsterdebugger
$ cd monsterdebugger
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/svn/trunk
$ git co remotes/svn/trunk
Note: checking out 'remotes/svn/trunk'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. <And so on...>
```

I guess I'm not fully understanding what's going on under the hood here. Shouldn't remotes/svn/trunk be a tracking branch against the svn repo? Why did I end up with a detached head?

Comment: Isn't `master` your tracking branch?  Why do you want to check out the remote branch?  Anyway, I think your question is a duplicate of this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head.  In essence, any time you check out a branch that's not "yours" (like a remote branch), you get a detached HEAD.

Comment: *Is* master my tracking branch? That's a fascinating question! It's not QUITE a dupe question because it's specifically about git-svn, although that probably doesn't make as much of a difference as I'm concerned it does.

Comment: yes, it probably is.  Check out `master` and do `git svn dcommit --dry-run` and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because it's a remote branch.  You need to create a local branch for it, with something like:

```
git checkout -b my-trunk remotes/svn/trunk
```